# Saving my dataset as a csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export

I currently have a json file i downloaded from github of a dataset that I edited by adding columns of values. How would I export my newly edited dataset as a csv file that I could upload back to github?

Currently my data is saved as:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxx.json' #example of raw url taken from github
df = pd.read_json(url) #dataset from json file

df['H_values'] = output #new column added of values
```

Since I updated the original dataset (df) with a column called "H_values" I would like to export this version of the dataset as a csv file (the last line of the code is the updated data). Thanks!

Comment: You first need to have a rule in mind that explains how the json data will correspond to csv data. It might not be possible, or at least in any remotely *useful* way. JSON describes a tree structure; CSV only describes a two-dimensional grid of values. However, since you apparently have a specific kind of JSON of the sort that `pandas` can make a table out of - it doesn't matter where the data came from, you save a DataFrame to csv the same way regardless. Please see the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

> df.to_csv("output.csv")

Check the Doc on pandas librairy for more information, on the fonction and its parameter

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for dataframes suggest an option to convert one into a *.csv like string: [Link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Now you just need to save this in the file:

```
with open("Output.csv", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(df.to_csv(index=False))
```

for more options I refere to the doc-link above.